# Why does the Jacobian of a transformation never vanishing implies that the transformation is onto

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, transformation

It could easily be shown that when jacobian never vanishes a continuously differentiable function is one to one. But we simply say that if jacobian never vanishes then the inverse transformation exists. How? How did we make sure that it's onto.

Comment: Not true: the function $\arctan x$ has a nowhere vanishing derivative but it is not onto.

Comment: Check the inverse function theorem. as uniquesolution says, what you write in your post is not accurate. However, it is true *locally*.